# Transform a One Word String Column from a Database into a new Alphagram Column with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dictionary of 270,000 words stored in a database. Is there a simple way to transform each of these words into an Alphagram in a new column?

I'm creating a game that requires players to guess the correct word from an alphagram.

Comment: Random alphagram? Each word has exactly one alphagram... (Do you mean anagram?)

Comment: Have you tried google yet?

Comment: @jarlh Sorry my mistake, I want the alphagram of each word. And yes to dfundako

Comment: Don't miss that one alphagram can have several correct words.

Comment: @jarlh Quite right, the front end will deal with that I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **An [alphagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphagram) of a word (or of any group of letters) consists of the word's letters arranged in alphabetical order.**
>
> For example, the alphagram of *alphagram* is *aaaghlmpr*. Two words are anagrams of each other if and only if they have the same alphagram.

You can use `CROSS APPLY` combined with `SUBSTRING` and tally table:

```
SELECT word, LOWER(c.alphagram) AS alphagram
FROM #dict
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT '' + sub.character               -- joining characters together
  FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(word, v.r, 1) AS character
    FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name)
              FROM master..spt_values) v  -- you can use own number query if needed
    WHERE v.r <= LEN(word)
  ) sub
  ORDER BY sub.character
  FOR XML PATH('')
) c(alphagram)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411287)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for this!